# Bind slider to scrollviewer silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I want to bind a slider to a scrollviewer control.
Whenever the slider moves, the scrollviewer should reflect it and vice versa.
Please help.(Silverlight)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can simply bind slider to your scrolviewerin the following way. when the scroll event of scrollbar will fire you can get value of scrollbar position then reflect it in slider. same goes for slider to sdcrollviewer too. I think thats olves your problem, isn't it?

Comment: though I am new to silverlight but i think this approach will work because i myself applied it

Comment: I actually had this one solved myself way before... and Bingo, this was the technique :)

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/95746/Exposing-and-Binding-to-a-Silverlight-ScrollViewer) you can see an attached behaviour to `ScrollViewer` that exposes the Vertical and Horizontal offset so you can bind to them like:

```
<ScrollViewer 
     local:ScrollViewerBinding.VerticalOffset="{Binding Value, ElementName=Slider, Mode=TwoWay}">
     ...
</ScrollViewer>
```